# Bosch Refrigerator turns off by itself and doesn't come back on

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

The title is pretty much it

- Refrigerator turns off
- I unplug the cord for 20 seconds
- I plug it back in - it works again (2nd time this happened)

---

Things I tried / checked :

- resetting breaker (no effect)
- plugging in and out in the same socket (fridge still off)
- plugging into different socket (fridge still off)
- the back of the fridge isn't dusty

To note - it is pretty cold here right now (possibly colder than the set fridge temperature. I left it in the 'off' state for half a day but it never turned back on.
My assumption also is that even when the auto-regulator stuff does its thing, the light should still come on/off when door is open.

How can I troubleshoot this before calling in a technician.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you know outlet is hot (plug in a lamp or radio to test) turn thermostat all the down - cold as possible & see if comes on. If is still dead, no interior light or anything check the cord for damage. Trace cord back to inverter/power block & see if there is a reset button or switch or a small fuse. If so reset there. Be very careful you don't get shocked. Something is overheating somewhere in the Refrigerator & tripping a reset or breaker. If it is too cold around the fridge it WILL shutdown the compressor but the light should at least still light. Otherwise is an electrical problem w/fridge. At that point, call a tech. Either way, good luck w/it.